# fill struct members where struct type is templated

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function `getmp()` which fills some key value pairs and returns.

```
map<string, string> getmp()
{
    map<string, string> mp;
    //fill mp

    return mp;
}
```

The key value pairs would be values for variables for one of the below structs(will be more of these). There would be an `id` member that will identify the struct to which these values correspond.

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    string b;
};

struct B
{
    string c;
};
```

Now i want to fill the correct struct using this `map`.

```
template<typename T>
T* fill(map<string, string> mp)
{
    T *obj = new T();

    //if T is A
    obj->a = stoi(mp["a"]);
    obj->b = mp["b"];

    //else if T is B
    obj->c = mp["c"];

    return obj;
}
```

and would be called from

```
int main()
{
    map<string, string> mp = getmp();
    // fill mp for A if mp["id"] = 1
    A *a = fill<A>(mp);

    //else fill mp for B if mp["id"] 2
    B *b = fill<B>(mp);
    return 0;
}
```

I can maintain a separate mapping to identify `id` `1` with `A` and `id` `2` with `B`.
What sort of additional mapping should be there for this with which i can identify the correct template parameter `A` and `B`?

How can i write my `fill()` to identify what values to fill?

Comment: template specialization, however, I dont understand what you expect to gain that you wouldnt get from writing plain boring constructors for those structs

Comment: Template specialization could be used to adapt structs that are defined by some other library. In general, you can use the default instantiation of the template to call through to the struct's constructor, and use the template specialization to support types for which you can't add a new constructor (such as std types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in C++ before 17 with template specialization:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct B
{
    std::string a;
    int b;
};

struct C
{
    std::string c;
};

using property_map = std::map<std::string, std::string>;

// template declaration. We purposley do not include a definition of the general function. 
template<typename T>
T* fill(property_map const& pm);

//specialization for struct A 
template<>
A* fill<A>(property_map const& pm)
{
    // ...
    return new A;
}

//specialization for struct B
template<>
B* fill<B>(property_map const& pm)
{
    // ...
    return new B;
}

void do_the_needful(property_map const& pm)
{
    auto a = fill<A>(pm);
    auto b = fill<B>(pm);
    // auto c = fill<C>(pm); // -> will fail to link since no specialization for C was defined. 
}
```

If you want the compiler to fail at compile time with a more descriptive error message when a specialization is forgotten, you can use a static_assert in the definition of the general case, like so:

```
// a template-dependent type that will always be false
template<typename T> 
using always_false = std::false_type;

// template general case -- we cause a compiler error to let the user know that they forgot to define the specialization. 
template<typename T>
T* fill(property_map const& pm)
{
    static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "Don't know how to unpack the property map into this struct type. Did you forget to add a specialization of fill<T>?");
}
```

This will cause an attempt to use the un-specialized `fill<C>` to fail with something like:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'T* fill(const property_map&) [with T = C; property_map = std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]':

<source>:55:28:   required from here

<source>:31:23: error: static assertion failed: Don't know how to unpack the property map into this struct type. Did you forget to add a specialization of fill<T>?

         static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "Don't know how to unpack the property map into this struct type. Did you forget to add a specialization of fill<T>?");

                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: This solves my problem but i am wondering what should be my mapping be to be used in `do_the_needful`. I will be using `pm[id]` to find out if `fill<A>` or `fill<B>` to be called

Comment: I'd just use an if-chain to branch on the id.

Comment: What are you actually doing with these structures once they're created? Do they get returned from the function as a common base class?

Comment: I actually pass them to different functions using function pointers that i have already stored.

Answer (score 1):

with C++17, you might use `if constexpr`:

```
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> fill(map<string, string> mp)
{
    auto obj = std::make_unique<T>();

    if constexpr (std::is_same<A, T>::value) {
        obj->a = stoi(mp["a"]);
        obj->b = mp["b"];
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<B, T>::value) {
        obj->c = mp["c"];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Before, you might use specialization:

```
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> fill(map<string, string> mp)
{
    return std::make_unique<T>();
}

template <>
std::unique_ptr<A> fill(map<string, string> mp)
{
    auto obj = std::make_unique<A>();

    obj->a = stoi(mp["a"]);
    obj->b = mp["b"];
    return obj;
}

template <>
std::unique_ptr<B> fill(map<string, string> mp)
{
    auto obj = std::make_unique<A>();

    obj->c = mp["c"];
    return obj;
}
```